# Stored procedure in nHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to CREATE (not query) a stored procedure with nhibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `<database-object>`

[5.6. Auxiliary Database Objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-database-object)